# Selectize form validation - find out if an option has been chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using selectize for my drop down menus and I'm trying to do form validation.  Each of the menus has class .code_select, and I want to know if an option has been selected on all of them. My code should determine if something is selected, and if not add the ID of the dropdown to an array called empty_fields.  However, my dropdowns are all ending up in the array whether they have a selected option or not.  This is my code:

```
$(".code_select").each(function(){
   if ($(this).find('option:selected').length === 0) {
       empty_fields.push($(this).attr("id")+'-selectized');
       submitForm=false;
     }                
});
```

An example of one of the inputs:

```
<div class='col-4'>
     <input type='text' class='form-control code_select' id='5-tree-Betpap-stdCodeSelect' name='5-tree-Betpap-stdCode' aria-label='Tree Metric Field 5  Standard Code select'>
</div>
```

And my selectize initialization:

```
// initialize newCodes selectize control      
   newCodesSelect[index] = $(this).selectize({         
        valueField: 'id',
        labelField: 'label',
        create: false,
        hideSelected: false,
        options: listOptions[listType],          
        searchField: 'label',
        placeholder: "Choose " + listType + " codes (type to search)",
        maxItems: 1,
            });
     //This stores the selectize object to a variable
     newCodesSelectize[index] = newCodesSelect[index][0].selectize;
```

How do I determine if the select is still on the "placeholder" when my placeholder has a variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is what worked for me.  I had to use .selectize-control as the selector and find if any of the items have data-attribute=null.

```
        $('#nextBtn').click(function() {  
            console.log("Next Button - adding  hidden fields");  
            //remove any left over error formatting
            $('.requiredField').removeClass('requiredField');
            var fld_text="";
            $('#error-messages').html(fld_text);
            // validate form before submit
            var empty_fields=[];
            var submitForm=true;
            $(".code_description").each(function(){
                if ($(this).val()==="") {                   
                    empty_fields.push($(this).attr("id"));
                    submitForm=false;
                }
            });
           
            $(".selectize-control").each(function(){
                if ($(this).find(".item").attr('data-value') == null) {
                    empty_fields.push($(this).prev("input").attr("id")+'-selectized');
                }                
            });
            empty_fields.forEach(function(element) { 
                if (element!=="undefined-selectized") submitForm=false;
            });
            if (submitForm===true) {
                $('#nextForm').submit();
            }
            else {
                fld_text="<p>Review required fields</p>";
                $('#error-messages').html(fld_text);          
                empty_fields.forEach(function(element) { 
                    if (element!=="undefined-selectized") $("#"+element).addClass("requiredField");
                });
            }
        });
```